# How do I attach an event to an array of select boxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of select boxes, with a class "taskcompleted". I want to be able to do something when a box is changed.

```
 <select class = "taskcompleted" >
   <option value="No">No</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 </select>
```

I have used this javascript code

```
  function initselects() {
    var myselects = $('.taskcompleted');
    myselects.each( function(){ // any select that changes.
      console.log( $(this).val() );
    }).change();
  }
```

When the page loads, it is logging a change for each select box. I do not want this to happen. I want to only log a change after the page as has loaded.

Comment: Since you're using a `class` to identify the element the function will affect any element with that `class`. Use an `id` if you just want one select box to  be affected.

Comment: `.change();` you are calling change?? So if you do not want it to be called, why are you calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `change()` to attach the event to each `select`, like this:

```
function initselects() {
    $('.taskcompleted').change(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
}
```

Comment: `.change()` triggers a change doesn't it? The OP says they don't want this to happen - at least I think that's what they mean

Comment: @DarrenSweeney ah yes - I missed the sneaky `.change()` at the end, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this you mean? This will add change handlers to all selects with class `taskcompleted`

The problem you have it that you're adding `.change()` to the end which actually triggers the change you don't want to happen - so instead, just listen for it

```
function initselects() {
    $('select.taskcompleted').on('change', function() {
        // do something
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the logging at page load, then simply remove change() from the end.
In general you can use it like that

JavaScript:

```
var myselects = $('.taskcompleted');
myselects.change( function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('name') + ': ' +  $(this).val() );
});
```

HTML:

```
 <select name="1stselectbox" class = "taskcompleted" >
   <option value="No">No</option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 </select>
 <select name="2ndselectbox" class = "taskcompleted" >
   <option value="Maybe">Maybe</option>
   <option value="dontknow">I don't know</option>
 </select>
```

So you set the change listener directly on the jQuery objects, no need to use a loop (*each*). The example above will even print which select box was selected (might be useful). E.g. the output will be when changing the first box to Yes: `1stselectbox: Yes`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x8jwy92h/